# Set EclipseProject.referencedProjects using dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am creating Eclipse project files as shown:

```
eclipse {
    project {
        natures 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature'
        buildCommand 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder'
    }
    classpath {
        downloadSources true
        downloadJavadoc true
    }
}
```

I have a multi-project gradle build where projects reference each other and 3rd party libs.  For `projectA`, its dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':projectB')
    compile project(':projectC')

    compile "com.google.guava:guava:${VER_GUAVA}"
}
```

This works great, except that the generated projects don't reference each other.  It builds just fine, but it means that if I refactor something in `projectB`, references in `projectA` aren't refactored with it.  The fix is apparently to set the `referencedProjects` variable of the `eclipse` configuration, but I'd  like for this to be automatically populated based on the dependencies.  Something like:

```
eclipse {
    project {
        referencedProjects dependencies.grep(dep is project)
        ...
```

Anybody have any hints?

Comment: If I create a new Gradle project in Eclipse using "flat mulyiproject" template then there is product and my-lib projects created where product depends on my-lib via Gradle compile dependency. Yet when i rename CoolLib#niceMethod() to CoolLib#bestMethod() it completes the refactoring correctly I think. Wonder what are the differences between your setup and the setup from the template...

Comment: Do you mean the template at 7.3.3 here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up fixing it:

```
// add all project dependencies as referencedProjects
tasks.cleanEclipse.doLast {
    project.configurations.stream()
    .flatMap({config -> config.dependencies.stream()})      // get all deps
    .filter({dep -> dep instanceof ProjectDependency})      // that are Projects
    .forEach({dep -> eclipse.project.referencedProjects.add(dep.name)}) // and add to referencedProjects
}
// always create "fresh" projects
tasks.eclipse.dependsOn(cleanEclipse)
```

Probably ought to mention that I'm using the [wuff](https://github.com/akhikhl/wuff) plugin because I'm in an OSGI environment, and it does tricks on the dependencies.  That might be the reason that I'm not getting this automatically, but the above snippet fixes it pretty easily.